# Node: npm basic-ftp, async await is not working in foreach loop

Tags: node.js, foreach, async-await, ftp

Below is the FTP folder structure:

```
12341
    abc.json
    xyz.json
12342
    pqr.json
    asd.json
12343
    jkl.json
    aaa.json
```

Now in node script, I'm using [Basic FTP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-ftp) to connect the FTP.

I have array like `[12341,12342,12343]` so I'm looping this array as below:

```
async.forEachOf(fileArray, async function(data, index, callback) 
{ 
    var list2 = await client.list(data+'/');

    async.forEachOf(list2, function(data, index, callback2) 
    { 
        var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

        latestFiles.push(data);
        
        callback2();
    },
    async function (err)
    {
        console.log("*****************************");
        console.log(latestFiles)

        callback();
    })
},
function (err) 
{
    console.log(err)
})
```

Above code is works fine if there is only one folder name in the array, but it is not working for multiple folders in loop.

> The error is as below:

```
Error: User launched a task while another one is still running. Forgot to use 'await' or '.then()'?
```

but I'm already using await here `await client.list(data+'/');`

Comment: You should not use await inside forEach because it does not block the main execution thread. It only blocks the function defined inside forEach. You should use a simple 'for' loop.

Comment: Check out this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop